# Is there an alternative to .replace() in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code. I am very new to python and before I jump to building tools I want to know the basics. Is this good code? Is there any way it can be improved? Heres the thing the .replace() had to be used 4 times. Is there any way I can replace ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, NOUN, and VERB all at once using user input? Note: I am reading AUTOMATE THE BORING STUFF WITH PYTHON practical programming for total beginners page:195 Mad Libs. Also I am on linux ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Usage: ./mad_libs.py start
# This program finds any .txt document to look for instances of ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, NOUN, and VERB within the file.
# these instances will be replaced by user input



import sys, os, time

# This opens any .txt file within the current working directory
try:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'start':
        for file in os.listdir('.'):
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                print('Opening text file...')
                time.sleep(5)
                os.system('clear')
                open_file = open(file, 'r')
                read_open_file = open_file.read()
                contents_of_the_file = str(read_open_file)

# If the user does not run ./mad_libs.py start print this and close the program
except IndexError:
    print('''Usage: ./mad_libs.py start
This program grabs a text file in the current working directory. The text file must contain any of the
following; ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, NOUN, VERB in capital letters each. Any instances will be replaced with
user input.
''')
    sys.exit()

# This asks the user for an adjective, adverb, noun, and verb
print('Give me an adjective')
ADJECTIVE = raw_input()
print('Give me an adverb')
ADVERB = raw_input()
print('Give me a noun')
NOUN = raw_input()
print('Give me a verb')
VERB = raw_input()

# Anything in the file containing ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, and VERB will be replaced with user input
modification_to_file_1 = contents_of_the_file.replace('ADJECTIVE', ADJECTIVE)
modification_to_file_2 = modification_to_file_1.replace('NOUN', NOUN)
modification_to_file_3 = modification_to_file_2.replace('ADVERB', ADVERB)
final_text = modification_to_file_3.replace('VERB', VERB)

# Finished new content is printed to user
os.system('clear')
print(final_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually looks pretty good. This question would really be more appropriate on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Here's what I might do... in your original code you actually had a mistake - you were looping through all of the files in your directory, but you were only dealing with the text in the last file. This shifts some things around a little bit, but will actually work for multiple files in one directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Usage: ./mad_libs.py start
# This program finds any .txt document to look for instances of ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, NOUN, and VERB within the file.
# these instances will be replaced by user input



import sys, os, time

# This opens any .txt file within the current working directory
try:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() != 'start':
        sys.exit()
except IndexError:
    # If the user does not run ./mad_libs.py start print this and close the program

    print('''Usage: ./mad_libs.py start
This program grabs a text file in the current working directory. The text file must contain any of the
following; ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, NOUN, VERB in capital letters each. Any instances will be replaced with
user input.
''')
    sys.exit()

# This asks the user for an adjective, adverb, noun, and verb
print('Give me an adjective')
adjective = raw_input()
print('Give me an adverb')
adverb = raw_input()
print('Give me a noun')
noun = raw_input()
print('Give me a verb')
verb = raw_input()

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        print('Opening text file...')
        time.sleep(5)
        os.system('clear')
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()

    for word in (adjective, noun, adverb, verb):
        text = text.replace('ADJECTIVE', adjective)
        text = text.replace('NOUN', noun)
        text = text.replace('ADVERB', adverb)
        text = text.replace('VERB', verb)

        os.system('clear')
        print(text)
```

Comment: very very nice. appreciate that link and that code!

Answer (score 0):

Don't need 4 replace statements. It can be reduced to `final_text=contents_of_the_file.replace('ADJECTIVE', ADJECTIVE).replace('NOUN', NOUN).replace('ADVERB', ADVERB).replace('VERB', VERB)`

You can also try using regex for replacing multiple strings.

Comment: Thank you, I will play with the regex again. You answered my question amazingly!

Comment: Regex replace wouldn't work any differently, and would just be more prone to errors.

Comment: Actually, you still use 4 replace statements.